# Little help with regex

Tags: php, regex, split

how can I match these:

```
(1, 'asd', 'asd2')
```

but not match this:

```
(1, '(data)', 0)
```

I want to match the ( and ), but not match ( and ) inside ( and ).

Actually these are queries and I want to split them via preg_split.

```
/[\(*\)]+/
```

splits them, but also splits ( and ) inside them, how can I fix this?

Example:

The data is:

(1, 'user1', 1, 0, 0, 0)(2, 'user(2)', 1, 0, 0, 1)

I want to split them as:

```
Array(
    0 => (1, 'user1', 1, 0, 0, 0)
    1 => (2, 'user(2)', 1, 0, 0, 1)
);
```

instead of it, its splitted as:

```
Array(
    0 => (1, 'user1', 1, 0, 0, 0)
    1 => (2, 'user
    2 => 2
    3 => ', 1, 0, 0, 1)
);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what output you want from these two examples?

Comment: Not strictly a regular expression, you'd have to use the recursive extensions of some regex engines out there.

Comment: You sure that you want /[\(*\)]+/ and not /[\(.*\)]+/

Comment: @Layke, it doesn't work that way.If I add . to it it searches for (.ANY) and not (ANY), because of the []'s.But if I remove []'s the code doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex Emilov, Thank you for the clarification! :-) I find this a task not well suited for preg_split, since you have to count opening and closing parentheses. Maybe go for something à la what [Gabi Purcaru](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274483/little-help-with-regex/7274690#7274690) mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex for this would be a little nasty. Instead, you can iterate over the entire string and decide where to split:

- If it's a `)`, split there. (I'm assuming the brackets are balanced in the string and can't be nested)
- If it's a `'`, ignore any `)` until a closing `'` (If it can be escaped, you can look at the previous characters for an odd number of `\`).

I think this is a more straight-forward solution than a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `preg_split` for that (as you don't match borders, but lengthier patterns). But it might be possible with a `preg_match_all`:

```
 preg_match_all(':\( ((?R) | .)*? \):x', $source, $matches);
 print_r($matches[0]);
```

Instead of a `?R` recursive version, you could also just prepare the pattern for a single level of internal parenthesis. But that wouldn't look much simpler actually.

```
 :\( ( [^()]* | \( [^()]* \) )+ \):x
```

Comment: This works very well. Could you please describe briefly how your pattern works? I'm not too familiar with recursiveness in regex.

Comment: @poplitea it's very simple actually: `(?R)` matches the whole regex itself. That's all there is to know about it. To put it to good use takes some practice though

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru Thank you, good to know! I don't doubt it, recursiveness always requires a sharp mind / some practice... :-)

Comment: @poplitea: It's more like a bit of patience and trial and error actually :} The [pcrepattern.3](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcrepattern) man page explains the syntax behind it. But it's really best to think of the abstracted case, where you just put one other level of your whole regex into the `?R` spot.

Answer (score 2):

Your grammar appears to be

```
list:  '(' num ( ',' term )(s?) ')'
term:  num | str
num:   /[0-9]+/
str:   /'[^']*'/
```

So the pattern is

```
/ \G \s* \( \s* [0-9]+ (?: \s* , \s* (?: [0-9]+ | '[^']*' ) )* \s* \) /x
```

Well, that's just for matching. Extraction is tricker if PHP works like Perl. If you want to do with with regex match, you have to do it in two passes.

First you extract the list:

```
/ \G \s* \( \s* ( [0-9]+ (?: \s* , \s* (?: [0-9]+ | '[^']*' ) )* ) \s* \) /x
```

Then you extract the terms from the list:

```
/ \G \s* ( [0-9]+ | '[^']*' ) (?: \s* , )? /x
```